# Openlitespeed and Docker (logging to stdout)

Tags: logging, wordpress

We are considering switching our Wordpress site from Apache2 to OpenLiteSpeed. We are just a little bit unsure how we can make OpenLiteSpeed log to stdout. Basically we run Docker containers and we have a FluentBit daemonset scraping the stdout and stderr and sending them to CloudWatch. In order to see those logs we'd have to make the container output the logs to stdout. I just couldn't find an easy way to do it. Otherwise i'd probably make a sidecar container that tails the logs and either ships them to CloudWatch or outputs it as stdout but that feels kind of hacky.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.